# std::cin and std::getline() are overtaking inputs from GetAsyncKeyState()

Tags: c++, getline

I have a problem with `GetAsyncKeyState()` and `std::getline()`/`std::cin`.

My program checks for pressed keys using `GetAsyncKeyState()`. This is working fine. But whenever I `cin` or `getline` a variable after that, it still has the character I pressed before.

No solution worked, like `cin.ignore()` or `cin.flush()` :(

```cpp
bool keyPressed[5]; 
          
int key_ascii_nums[5]= {65, 69, 68, 67, 76};  
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    if(GetAsyncKeyState(key_ascii_nums[i]) & 0x8000)
        keyPressed[i] = true;
    else 
        keyPressed[i] = false;
}

string str;
getline(cin, str);
```

`str` always starts with the character I gave before. How can I remove it?

Comment: `GetAsyncKeyState` doesn't read any characters from any stream. It checks whether physical keys on the keyboard are currently pressed, is all. These keys still perform their usual action when pressed, such as entering characters into the standard input stream.

Comment: Where those characters will sit in standard in's buffer until you read them out.

Comment: But how do I remove the character?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by using a different input method.

Insted of writing it to a bool array I used

```
switch (toupper(_getch()))
{
    case 'L': 
      // do stuff
      break;
    default:
      break;
```

}

from conio.h